# 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation angular

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to use the party-js lib in order to get the confetti effect working in a angular project.
However when using following code i get an error saying that `this` has type any.
I tried using ':' and adding a type after but then i don't know what type I have to put after since it doesn't change the error and also gives me another one saying, that I now have 3 instead of 2 arguments.

```
document.querySelector(".button")!.addEventListener("click", function (e) { 
party.confetti(this:);
});
```

Comment: `this: HTMLElement party, { count: party.variation.range(20, 40), }` doesn't look like valid syntax. What does this mean?

Comment: Had the wrong thing in my clipboard since i tried out a few things to fix it. I changed it back to the original Code snipped i found on https://party.js.org/docs.
(Added the '!' since there was an Error saying the return of the querySelector might be null.

Comment: `party.confetti(this:);` doesn't look like valid syntax, too. Do you have question that isn't answered in the duplicate?

Comment: They this: type doesn't work for me, however i found another answer that stated to change some stuff in the tsconfig.json
´´´// disable this rule:
// "strict": true,

// enable this rule:
"noImplicitAny": false´´´

If i do that, the error disappears obviously but then the full content of the site is missing. The Syntax should be valid since it's copied from their website.

Comment: You disabled the type check. Why do you use TypeScript if you disable the checks? Without checks, you could also use JavaScript.